# How to determine the smaller time C#

Tags: c#, file, timer, converters, writealltext

I require a way to store the smallest time to replace any existing, but currently what I have tried [below] doesn't work and may sometimes say that 2:38.4 is smaller than 2:20.1.

In the text file

```
88:88:8
```

In the form 3 text boxes

```
timerMin
timerSec
timerMil
```

Writing into a correct path.

```
                using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(pathPlayer + player[id].name + "\\time.txt"))
                {
                    string z = reader.ReadLine();
                    string[] zsplit = z.Split(':');
                    reader.Close();
                    fileMin = Convert.ToInt32(timerMinute.Text);
                    recMin = Convert.ToInt32(zsplit[0]);
                    if (fileMin < recMin)
                    {
                        File.WriteAllText(pathPlayer + player[id].name + "\\time.txt", timerMinute.Text + ":" + timerSecond.Text + ":" + timerMili.Text);
                        newPersonalRecord = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        fileSec = Convert.ToInt32(timerSecond.Text);
                        recSec = Convert.ToInt32(zsplit[1]);
                        if (fileSec < recSec)
                        {
                            File.WriteAllText(pathPlayer + player[id].name + "\\time.txt", timerMinute.Text + ":" + timerSecond.Text + ":" + timerMili.Text);
                            newPersonalRecord = true;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            fileMil = Convert.ToInt32(timerMili.Text);
                            recMil = Convert.ToInt32(zsplit[1]);
                            if (fileMil < recMil)
                            {
                                File.WriteAllText(pathPlayer + player[id].name + "\\time.txt", timerMinute.Text + ":" + timerSecond.Text + ":" + timerMili.Text);
                                newPersonalRecord = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
```

I have been working on this for quite a while and I cannot see where I have gone wrong, and help would be brilliant.

Thanks

Comment: Timespan has a parse method I would use it to parse your timespans and compare those.

Comment: _In the text file `88:88:8`_ - that won't Parse as a TimeSpan. Is that literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are comparing the text boxes when you should be comparing the TimeSpans

if the strings in the file do not exceeds the time of a day (up to "23:59:59")
then you can use the strings to create TimeSpans by doing `TimeSpan.Parse("18:44:08");` and compare them like

```
                fileMin = new TimeSpan(0, 0, int.Parse(timerMin), int.Parse(timerSec), int.Parse(timerMil));
                recTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(z);

                if(fileMin > recTimeSpan)
                {// Your code}
                else
                {// Your code}
```

you can always do

```
                recTimeSpan = new TimeSpan(0, 0, int.Parse(zsplit[0]), int.Parse(zsplit[1]), int.Parse(zsplit[2]));
```

Comment: What timespans? I believe the OP is comparing an integer from a textbox to an integer from a file (for each part) - which should be fine. Also, the time is not hours, minutes, seconds. It is minutes, seconds, milliseconds.. are you reading the same question as me?

Comment: @musefan he says the file contains string like: "88:88:8"

Comment: Yeah, and is 88 a valid minute or second? no, so that value should be assumed to indicate an undetermined format, where `8` represents a digit. The OP then shows clearly that his 3 components are minutes, seconds and milliseconds due to his variable naming

Answer (score 1):

This is more of a design quip but I would strongly suggest you use the [TimeSpan](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.aspx) class for something like this rather than integers; it would make your code a lot easier to both write and read. You could construct a new TimeSpan off of the time data you're retrieving and then just use one comparison operator to determine whether it's greater, less than or equal to the existing record, rather than one for seconds and milliseconds without minutes.

[DateTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.aspx) could also work if you use it to track start and end times (you can find the difference between DateTimes as a TimeSpan very easily by just using the subtraction operator)

For example:

```
DateTime StartTime
DateTime EndTime 
TimeSpan difference = EndTime = StartTime
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of repetition that you should aim to eliminate. You can also use `TimeSpan` to store the values and compare them.

Try something like this:

```
string filePath = pathPlayer + player[id].name + "\\time.txt";
string z = null;
using (TextReader reader = File.OpenText(filePath))
{
    z = reader.ReadLine();
}
string[] zsplit = z.Split(':');

//Create a timespan from the values read from the .txt file
TimeSpan fileTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, int.parse(zsplit[0]), int.parse(zsplit[1]), int.parse(zsplit[2]));
//Create a timespan from the values stored in the Textbox controls
TimeSpan inputTime = new TimeSpan(0, 0, int.parse(timerMinute.Text), int.parse(timerSecond.Text), int.parse(timerMili.Text));

//Check if the new TextBox time is faster than the time stored in the file
if(inputTime < fileTime)
{
    //new faster time, so update the file
    File.WriteAllText(filePath, inputTime.ToString("mm:ss:f"));
    newPersonalRecord = true;
}
```

A few things to note:

- There is no validation on the input, so invalid data will crash the app (you should add validation, see: [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx)). You will also want to validate `z` is not null, and `zsplit` has a `Length` of atleast `3`
- Your naming of `fileMin` and `recMin` didn't match up with your data source, I renamed them to `fileTime` and `inputTime` to be more clear
- This example checks if `inputTime` is less than `fileTime`, if you want it the other way then just switch them around in the `if` statement
- The use of `TimeSpan` in this example assumes that the minute component can never be greater than `59`